# one page horizontal site not centered on resize

Tags: jquery, html, css, resize

I'm developing my first one-page horizontal website using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and the [scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin. The site has 3 screens and starts centered (showing the middle screen). To accomplish this, the logical approach for me was to make `<body>` have `width:300%;`, with each screen having `width:33.3333%;`. When you click a `<a>`, jQuery sends you to another screen, going left or right.

This works great, however when I try to resize my window I lose all structure, the widths stop making sense. I would like to know what I can do to fix this, but more importantly I would like to understand why this happens.

Here's [Mr. Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cthulhu/rKF2q/1/). Resize your window and you'll see what's wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-evaluated this as you mentioned in one of the comments on Luke's answer that you need to remember where you have been last.

You need to track where you are and then go back to there after re-sizing.
Use code similar to this:

```
var lastPosition = "middle";
var $body = $('html, body');

window.scrollTo(($(document).width() - $(window).width()) / 2, 0);

$('#go_left').click(function() {
    $body.scrollTo('0px', 800);
    lastPosition = "left";
});
$('#go_right').click(function() {
    $body.scrollTo('100%', 800);
    lastPosition = "right";
});
$('#left_link').click(function() {
    $body.scrollTo('50%', 800);
    lastPosition = "middle";
});
$('#right_link').click(function() {
    $('html, body').scrollTo('50%', 800);
    lastPosition = "middle";
});

$(window).off('resize.menu').on('resize.menu', function() {    
    switch(lastPosition)
    {
        case "left":
            $body.scrollTo('0px', 0);
            break;
        case "middle":
            $body.scrollTo('50%', 0);
            break;
        case "right":
            $body.scrollTo('100%', 0);
            break;
    }
})​
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaxtQ/1/)

I also cached the body element so you do not have to constantly re-traverse to it when scrolling but that added little performance gain.

As before, remember to unbind the event when you leave the page or you could end up with a memory-leak.

I still haven't managed to get rid of the lagging re-positioning but that is something to work on after.

**Edit**
Finally found a way to minimise the lag/flickering on resize.

Use `scrollLeft()` instead in the resize method it works better, not perfect/prefect but much much better:

```
$(window).off('resize.menu').on('resize.menu', function() {    
    var elementToScrollTo = "div#main";

    switch(lastPosition)
    {
        case "left":
            elementToScrollTo = "div#left";
            break;
        case "middle":
            elementToScrollTo = "div#main";
            break;
        case "right":
            elementToScrollTo = "div#right";
            break;
    }

     $(window).scrollLeft($(elementToScrollTo).position().left);
})
```

Updated [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaxtQ/2/)

Comment: Perfect answer, outstanding job. Thanks mate.

Comment: @Cthulhu: Thanks. You are welcome. I couldn't figure out yet how to get rid of the re-size lagging. I update the answer if I find out.

Comment: @Cthulhu: Got the flickering sorted out now for you and updated the answer with it. Enjoy.

Comment: I didn't see any flickering testing on my pc yesterday. However, I believe there could be some issues on slower computers. Thanks for fixing this issue, even after I accepted your answer as correct. Not only you provided a great answer, I even learned a bit more about jQuery. Sorry I can't give you any more reputation, excellent work.

Comment: @Cthulhu: thank you, I'm glad I was able to help out. I never worked with `scrollTo()` before so it was very rewarding for me to learn about it too.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using scrollTo plugin, why not use "A DOM element (logically, child of the scrollable element)" when specifying where to scroll?
That is:

```
 $('html, body').scrollTo($('div#right'), 800);
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue, but it's a great advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`$(window).resize(function() {
    $('html, body').scrollTo('50%', 0);
});`

This might be just a little less laggy than Francois answer just because you don't have to recalculate the widths, because this code will get called for almost every pixel the window size changes to.

Comment: Works great. However, if I'm on the left div and I resize the window, it brings me back to the center div. Anyway I can resize and stay on the left?

Comment: @Cthulhu: I thought about this and re-worked my answer. It works but it still lags though. I'm going to check if this can be smoothed somehow too.

Answer (score 1):

Add this :

http://jsfiddle.net/EAzS9/1/

```
$(window).resize( function () {
    window.scrollTo(($(document).width() - $(window).width()) / 2, 0);
});
​
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're using scrollTo, even though you type a percentage value in, that is getting set as an absolute pixel value. Resizing the window does nothing to change that absolute pixel value unless you code in an event handler on the "resize" event to recalculate the scroll value.  If I were you, though, I'd work in absolute pixel values for something like this.  Define the width of each `.page` div in pixels, and wrap them all in a div with a very large width to make sure future pages will fit. Then, instead of scrolling, set the `left` offset of the wrapper.  The original [coda slider](http://kevinbatdorf.github.com/codaslider/) used this technique, and I imagine the current one still does.