# keep content centered on window resize - horizontal scroll one-page site

Tags: jquery, resize, scrollto, horizontal-scrolling

I have a similar problem and situation to the one answered in this thread: [one page horizontal site not centered on resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677560/one-page-horizontal-site-not-centered-on-resize), although I can't seem to get that solution to work for me.

I'm just learning javascript/jQuery and adding some basic responsive-ness, so it's a wonder that I have a working site at all. It's my first horizontal scrolling one-page site and somehow (magically, to me) I've gotten scrollTo and localScroll up and running, but I'd like to see the content remain centered on resize. If you're on the first slide with the image, it remains centered - but if you're on any other slide (credits/reel/contact) the widths all change and move around.

Take a look at http://dianeajax.maxsitedesign.com

I should mention it's running on Wordpress, in case that changes the answers. Please let me know if anything is unclear or if I should paste code somewhere; as I said I'm aware that I don't really know what I'm doing. Be kind. :)

Answer (score 0):

For posterity's sake:

### JS for NAV

```
$('.main-nav-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var toTarget = $(this).attr('href');
    history.pushState(null, null, toTarget);
    $(window).triggerHandler('hashchange');
});

$(window).on('hashchange', function () {
    if(!window.location.hash) return;
    var $target = $(window.location.hash);
    $('html, body').stop(true,false).animate({
        scrollLeft: $target.offset().left}, 900, function() {
            $(this).stop(true,false).animate({scrollTop:0})
        });
});
```

### JS for RESIZE

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var stayHere = $(window.location.hash);
    $('html, body').stop(true,false).scrollLeft( stayHere.offset().left );
});
```

Additional information regarding the CSS/HTML used: [Horizontal One-Page site won't go "backwards" to previous DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993231/horizontal-one-page-site-wont-go-backwards-to-previous-div/)

Comment: hi twf1985 - thank you for the answer on this old thread. Can you give me a little more info? The JS for NAV is self-explanatory and much simplifies what I had been doing, but the JS for RESIZE throws an error of "Cannot read property 'left' of undefined". In the linked article, the horizontal scroll is fine, but the demo there doesn't tackle what I'm trying to do either (keep the current hashtag position/slide centered on browser resize) so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot. This is the updated site link too: http://www.dianeciesla.com/

Comment: Hey @Max - If you've implemented the JS for Nav, can you confirm that the browser is showing the proper hash for each slide as they change? Based on that error, I'd guess that it isn't, as "undefined" would mean that there is no hash in the location. Make sure the script for nav (particularly the "history.pushState..." portion) is working properly.