# Horizontal One-Page site won't go "backwards" to previous DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, horizontal-scrolling

Quick backstory:

I had everything working perfectly, but after some time, I noticed it no longer functioned properly. The ability to go back a "page" is extremely important to me, so I set about undoing any recent changes I'd made. That didn't work, so I decided to recreate the framework (hoping to piece in the content to find the trouble spot), yet still the problem persists. I've distilled the code down to the basics below.

I used to be able to hit the back button, and I would be immediately taken to the previous panel. NOW, nothing happens except that the "#page_name" is changed and the current panel shifts 1px. If I've clicked a few links (thereby storing more of a history "trail"), then once I hit the back button a second time, I finally go back a state, but not to the right one.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gz9nW/

JQ

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.main-nav').on('click',function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       var target = $(this).attr("href");
       $target = $(target);

       $('html, body').stop().animate({
           'scrollLeft': $target.offset().left,
           'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
       }, 900, 'swing', function () {
           window.location.hash = target;
       });
   });
});
```

CSS

```
html {
font: 100% 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
height:100%;
width:100%;
margin:0%;
padding:0%;
}
body {
    font-size:1.25em;
    width:100%;
    margin:0%;
    padding:0%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

    header {
        width:100%;
        position:fixed;
        z-index:5000;
        top:0%;
        left:0%;
        padding:0%;
        margin:0%;
        background:silver;
        }


    /*################################ NAV ################################*/

        nav ul {
            list-style:none;
        }
            nav ul li {
                display:inline;
                margin-right:5px;
            }


/*################################ WRAPPER ################################*/

    .wrapper {
        width:1000%; /* #PAGES X 100% */
        height:100%;
    }

/*################################ PAGES ################################*/

        .page-container {
            width:10%; /* 1 / #PAGES */
            display:inline-block;
            vertical-align:top;
            padding:0%;
            margin:0%;
            margin-right:-5px;
        }
            .page-container:nth-child(even) {
                background:lightgreen;
            }
            .page-container:nth-child(odd) {
                background:lightblue;
            }
            .page-contents {
                padding:10% 0%;
                width:61%;
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;
                background:grey;
            }
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="main-nav" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="main-nav" href="#products">Products</a></li>
                <li><a class="main-nav" href="#services">Services</a></li>
                <li><a class="main-nav" href="#quote">Quote</a></li>
                <li><a class="main-nav" href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a class="main-nav" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="page-container" id="home">
            <div class="page-contents">
            home
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page-container" id="products">
            <div class="page-contents">        
            products
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page-container" id="part-list">
            <div class="page-contents">        
            part list catalog
            </div>
        </div>        
        <div class="page-container" id="services">
            <div class="page-contents">        
            services
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page-container" id="quote">
            <div class="page-contents">        
            quote request
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page-container" id="about">
            <div class="page-contents">        
            about
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page-container" id="contact">
            <div class="page-contents">        
            contact page
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page-container" id="inquiries">
            <div class="page-contents">        
            solution inquiries
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page-container" id="news">
            <div class="page-contents">        
            news
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page-container" id="legal">
            <div class="page-contents">        
            legal info
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

It's a huge blow to this project, as this specific functionality was something I was after. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That fiddle works in Firefox (27.0.1) for me.

Comment: I tried the fiddle and it works fine in Firefox (latest version).

Comment: I see the issue, using Chrome. If you navigate to the second page, then the third, then right-click in the fiddle window and click back, the third page, services, stays where it is but bumps over about 1 pixel. Can you elaborate on which browsers / devices you're targeting for this and whether you have any other functions or events that may be attached to this behavior?

Comment: @Lazerblade, I saw the behavior in all my browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera, and Safari; latest versions), so I didn't feel it necessary to mention. My bad. tcj, it worked in the beginning for me too. Very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your issue:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3N8wY/show)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.main-nav').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var toTarget = $(this).attr('href');
        history.pushState(null, null, toTarget);
        $(window).triggerHandler('hashchange');
    });
});

$(window).on('hashchange', function () {
    if(!window.location.hash) return;
    var $target = $(window.location.hash);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: $target.offset().left,
        scrollTop: $target.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing');
});
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, for the most part. In IE (latest version), it performs the function, but doesn't seem to rehash. In Opera, it won't go back to the home page (due to, I believe, the initial page not having a hash value).

Comment: It's been a little while, but I was wondering if you could take a look at a new problem I'm having using the script you provided: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677016/horizontal-one-page-site-mobile-webkit-scrolling-swiping-issues

Answer (score 0):

*I wanted to add this so that those who have trouble with cross-browser compliance when using Wolff's code can have some reprieve from banging their head against [...dealer's choice].*

### Back to Home Issue

Some browsers don't play nice when trying to go back to the home page, as it has no hashvalue.

**Home Page Hash Fix**

```
function hashHome() {
    var currentHash = location.hash;
    var homeHash = '#home';
    if (currentHash == '') {
        history.pushState(null, null, homeHash);
    }
}
hashHome();
```

---

### Webkit Simultaneous Scrolling Issue

A HUGE problem in some webkit browsers, specifically mobile (read iOS!!!), is that when you simultaneously scroll horizontally and vertically, what you end up with is a sputtering, jittery mess that lands you back where you started. Quite devastating, and very perplexing.

I initially thought this was due to the browser not hashing the new values, but I later realized that the new values were there, just not "reported" to the viewport. The iOS address bar (7+) doesn't reveal changes as they happen, only after tapping the address bar (DOI! *whoops*, should've tried that first thing...) did I figure it out. Call me crazy, but if your code relies on one thing (the new hashvalue), and that thing isn't visibly happening, you might assume (like I did) that the reason the code isn't working is because of the one thing you're "seeing" isn't happening.

**For complete explanation:** [Horizontal One-Page Site: Mobile-Webkit Scrolling & Swiping Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677016/horizontal-one-page-site-mobile-webkit-scrolling-swiping-issues/23220126#23220126)

**The click function remains the same as Wolff's.**

**Cross-browser Fix**

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {

    if(!window.location.hash) return;
    var target = $(window.location.hash);
    var targetHash = window.location.hash;

    var iOS = ( navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) ? true : false );

    var currentPosition = $(window).scrollLeft();

    var targetPosLeft = target.offset().left;

    var targetPosTop = target.offset().top;

    function unbindWindow() { $(window).unbind('scroll'); }

    function repositionWin() {
        unbindWindow();
        $(window).on('scroll', function() {
            var alteredPosLeft = $(window).scrollLeft();
            var alteredPosTop = $(window).scrollTop();          
            if (alteredPosLeft != targetPosLeft) {
                window.scrollTo(targetPosLeft, alteredPosTop),
                unbindWindow(),
                repositionWin();
            }           
        });
    }

    function fadePages() {
        if (targetPosLeft == currentPosition) {
        }
        else {
            function fadePageOut() {
                $('.page-container').stop(true,false).animate({
                    opacity: "0.25",
                    transition: "opacity 0.1s 0.0s ease"
                });
            }
            function fadePageIn() {
                $('.page-container').stop(true,false).animate({
                    opacity: "1.0",
                    transition: "opacity 0.3s 0.0s ease"
                });
            }
            fadePageOut();
            setTimeout (fadePageIn, 900);
        }
    }

    function pageChange() {
        if (jQuery.browser.mobile === true) {
            if (iOS === true) {
                unbindWindow();
                $('html,body').stop(true,false).animate({
                    scrollLeft: targetPosLeft}, 1400);
                    setTimeout (repositionWin, 1500);
            }
            else {
                unbindWindow();
                $('html,body').stop(true,false).animate({
                    scrollLeft: targetPosLeft}, 1200, function() {
                        $(this).stop(true,false).animate({
                            scrollTop: targetPosTop
                        }, 200, repositionWin);
                });
            }
        }
        else {
            fadePages();
            unbindWindow();
            $('html,body').stop(true,false).delay(100).animate({
                scrollLeft: targetPosLeft,
                scrollTop: targetPosTop
            }, 1300, repositionWin);
        }
    }   
    if ($('#mini-site-menu-button-container').is(':visible') === true && $('#main-menu-wrapper').hasClass('show-main-menu') === true) {
        setTimeout (pageChange, 300)
    }
    if ($('.footer-container').is(':visible') === true) {
        setTimeout (pageChange, 500)
    }
    if ($('.form-instructions-wrapper').hasClass('expand-form-instruct') === true) {
        setTimeout (pageChange, 500)
    }
    if ($('.quick-quote-container').hasClass('toggle-open') === true) {
        setTimeout (pageChange, 500)
    }
    if ($('#mini-site-menu-button-container').is(':visible') === false && $('.footer-container').is(':visible') === false && $('.form-instructions-wrapper').hasClass('expand-form-instruct') === false && $('.quick-quote-container').hasClass('toggle-open') === false) {
        pageChange();
    }
    if ($('#main-menu-wrapper').hasClass('show-main-menu') === false && $('.footer-container').is(':visible') === false && $('.form-instructions-wrapper').hasClass('expand-form-instruct') === false && $('.quick-quote-container').hasClass('toggle-open') === false) {
        pageChange();
    }

});
```

---

**Additional Notes**

I removed most of my additional code, but left the conditional statements on end to show how you might call the page change on a mobile site. Depending on how you choose to allow the user to navigate your page (I chose to pop my menu out from the left, hence the "toggle-open"), you'll want to allow your other animations time to complete before you fire the scrolling animation. It tends to be a lot for most mobile devices to handle all at once. I'm still too green to understand how animations que, so this is how I addressed it.

I also added a function to fade the page container while it's scrolling. If you're going from one end of the site to the other, there's quite a bit of leg work involved in traveling that far. That much content whizzing by can be a bit off-putting to watch. Fading it a little seems to dull the blow, and I daresay it adds a little something, as well.

Lastly, for touch enabled devices, I added a function that monitors and corrects the horizontal scroll position in between page changes. It's really easy to accidentally scroll left and right by swiping on a phone, so it seemed necessary.